# How do I filter table data using Angular and Angularfire when a button is clicked using multiple views?

Tags: angularjs, templates, angularfire, angular-filters

OK. I have searched for days for a suitable answer to my question, but I cannot find a relevant answer. It's possible that I have overlooked many things, but I am basically new to coding (+1 month).

I am working on an Angular + Firebase/Angularfire project that requires a todo app. It sounds fairly simple, but I am adding some extra features to it. One of the features that I have been having trouble with is filtering todos that are unfinished and those that are finished from one template to another.

What I would like to do is move all the todos that are marked "done", when clicked, to another table in another template view. So far, I've written 3 HTML templates: home (where the todos are entered), completed, and expired (I am still working on this one, which is another issue!). All of the templates are working when changing views using `ui-view` and a navigation button.

At the moment of the templates contain the same HTML table, so, of course, I am getting the same data in the tables when the data is placed in the "home" template. This is a non-issue; I knew that this would happen.

(Tried to post images, but I don't have 10 reputation points!) **Here's the Plnkr**: [My Todo App](http://plnkr.co/edit/VQLhUwTqugU8VorPORwg)

**The question is:** How can the data be filtered so that only those marked done appear in the "complete" template when checked on the "home" template? I know I have to write a filter, but I am not sure of the best way to go about it.

(I recently switched from a button to a checkbox just to make things a little easier for myself to see how things are working.)

```
<div class='row'> 
    <div class='col-md-10'>
    <table class='table table-hover'>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Todo</th>
                <th>Date Due</th>
                <th>Done</th>
                <th></th> 
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class='results' ng-repeat='todo in todos'>
                <td><span>{{$index + 1}}</scan></td>
                <td><span>{{todo.text}}</span></td>
                <td><span>{{todo.date}}</span></td>
                <td><input type='checkbox' ng-model='todo.done'><span class='done-{{todo.done}}'></span></td>
                <td><button class='btn btn-danger' ng-click='removeTodo(todo)'>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
```

This is the corresponding script:

```
app.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope, $firebase) {
  var ref = new Firebase('https://xxxx.firebaseio.com/');
  var sync = $firebase(ref);

  $scope.todos = sync.$asArray();

  $scope.addTodo = function() {
    $scope.todos.$add({
      text: $scope.newTodo,
      date: $scope.newDate,
      done: false,
      expired: false
    });
    $scope.newTodo = '';
    $scope.newDate = '';
  };

  $scope.removeTodo = function(todo) {
    $scope.todos.$remove(todo);
  };
});
```

To add to this, I've tried writing a function that would do this, but looking at this so long has culminated in Javascript brain drain. I've done something like:

```
$scope.completedTodos = function(todo) {
   $scope.todos ... (Have no idea what to do?)
};
```

Yes, this obviously does not work! That's why I am considering just filtering the data. I could be wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something simple that might help get you up and running.

First, add `ng-change` attribute for check-boxes for setting the Done value (in home.html and complete.html).  This will save the done value to firebase.

```
<input type='checkbox' ng-model='todo.done' ng-change="todos.$save(todo)">
```

Secondly, for the `complete.html` template, add this filter to your ng-repeat.

```
ng-repeat='todo in todos | filter:{done:true}'
```